# Haskell: LDAP Authentication

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a simple function that would bind to LDAP server and return a IO Bool value so that I can analyze the return in a conditional statement later.
This little snippet below works and prints an error if bind fails but it is not what I need.

```
import LDAP.Init
import LDAP.Exceptions

auth :: IO ()
auth = do
  c <- ldapOpen "10.1.1.11" 3268
  let bnd =ldapSimpleBind c "myusername@domain.local" "mypassword"
  catchLDAP bnd (\_ -> error "Wrong user name or password")
```

I get an error if I try to return anything but IO () by the function that deals with exception. I need it to return IO Bool.

'ldapSimpleBind' just throws an exception if unsuccessful and that's all. Catching exceptions will only allow me to return an IO ()
What I need is to return something meaningful so that I can do something useful with the return value.
I am clearly missing something as the signature of catchLDAP in the docs is :: IO a -> (LDAPException -> IO a) -> IO a

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bnd` action doesn't return `true` when it succeeds, and the error handler just calls `error`,

So it seems that you could just `let bnd' = bnd >> return true` ,

then, `catchLDAP bnd' $ \_ -> return false`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I realize that in the above example it just returns the error. It's my bad I posted example that works with IO () but I actually forgot to post the snippet that I tried with IO Bool and which gave me grief. It looks like I just messed up the parentheses in front of the bind operator. But never mind ... It all works now. Thanks for clearing it up for me.